# JasperReports: Convert Amount into Words

Tags: plsql, jasper-reports, oracle-apex

I am using *iReport 4.7*.

I want print amount in words.

For Example:
Assume Text field contains 1000 and i want print like  "One Thousand".

Is anyone tell the steps to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Process your datasource before passing it to the report.

Using ibm's [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) you can convert amount into words by doing something like

```
double num = 2718;
    RuleBasedNumberFormat formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.ENGLISH, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
    String result = formatter.format(num);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Will print

`two thousand seven hundred eighteen`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle database then try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($P{ParamName}, 'J'), 'Jsp')
FROM dual
```

This spells out whatever number you pass through `$P{ParamName}`. You can use this select clause in your main query's `SELECT` clause and use it.